# how to use R if statements to make distinctions between two options of a variable

Tags: r, if-statement, statistics

I am new to R and would like to understand how to use the if statement/if-else function to make distinctions between two options of a variable, which in my case would be gender. Specifically, i would like to use [this](https://C:%5CUsers%5CGiuli%5COneDrive%5CDocumenti%5CFinaccount.xlsx) dataset to see if there is a difference between men and women in having a bank account on their name(-1 and -2 are women and men, from 1:5 it's the options for the financial account).

```
dput(Finaccount)

> dput(head(Finaccount))
structure(list(finaccount = c("0", "0", "0", "2 6", "0", "0"), 
    genderresp = c(-2, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Next, i will create a chi squared table, but i would also find helpful any advice on how to show the direction of the data (so not only that there is a significance but that one gender has more bank accounts on their name than others ).

I am using other ways to make the gendered distinction, mostly by creating two datasets with subset or grepl like in the examples below but i am assuming there are easier ways.

```
RespSeason <-- data.frame(respjobhh, gendercleaned)
View(RespSeason)                                                              
RespseasonCleaned = na.omit(RespSeason)                                 
View(RespseasonCleaned)                                                             
Seasonwoman <-- subset(RespseasonCleaned, gendercleaned == "-2")                    
Seasonmen<-- subset(RespseasonCleaned, gendercleaned == "-1")
```

```
gender = hh_complete_fixed_cleaned[,22 ]
gendercleaned = na.omit(gender)jobhh = hh_complete_fixed_cleaned[, 128]
jobhhcleaned = na.omit(jobhh)
sapply(jobhhcleaned, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

data.frame(jobhh, gendercleaned)
View(jobhh, gendercleaned) 
genderjobbhh <-- data.frame(jobhh, gendercleaned)
View(genderjobbhh)

malehh <--genderjobbhh[!grepl('2', genderjobbhh$gendercleaned),]
View(malehh)
sapply(malehh, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
femalehh <--genderjobbhh[!grepl('1', genderjobbhh$gendercleaned),]
View(femalehh)
sapply(femalehh, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Thank you in advance for your contribution

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @Giulia Petrilli It would be great to see a small example of what you are trying to accomplish. I might be reading it wrong, but are you needing to recode -1/-2 to male/female, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

The below might help if you a looking to get a mean by a group:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 mutate(gender = if_else(gender == -1, "male", if_else(gender == -2, "female", "unknown"))) %>%
 group_by(gender) %>%
 summerize(mean_gender = mean(gender))
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 mutate(gender = as.character(gender),
        gender = recode(gender, "-1" = "male", "-2" = "female")) %>%
 group_by(gender) %>%
 summerize(mean_gender = mean(gender))
```